# Magento 2 Chmod Installation Problems

Tags: magento2, server-setup, putty

I am currently trying to install Magento 2 on my hosting package (shared), and have some trouble here with Chmod.

On Magento Webpage it is being said, that you have to change Chmod permissions pre-installation:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

So, I log in via PuTTy, use the user-name I was given by hosting provider (+ password) and try to run the commands, but what I get are two issues:

a) Algthough I am in the root folder of my website, I get the message:
Folder (...) not found - Why?
I installed and unzipped all into the root folder, so it must be there.
Also when I search for it via Is command, I get something like: No data

b) Still he runs the commands;
what I then get is the message: Not Owner
And this is strange.
I have used the main username given to me, But I am still not the owner of the content?!

Any clues?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Please check this link --- https://support.weltpixel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001868933-How-to-set-Magento-2-permissions-and-avoid-installation-errors